# Specs of Video on Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video

I created a video on Photoshop with specs being (WxH) 2560 x 768. Unfortunately I cannot render the video with these specs, Photoshop allows me a maximum height of 2304. How can I change the setting to have the right specs for my video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Image > Image Size` to reduce the size of your document. All layers will scale to meet a new size.